# Why i keep getting the same value for every iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a table which contains some text values. The main problem is that I have to first get them and then turn them into an array, so I've made a loop, checking for values in the table and when i try to get their content, it returns the same number. Here's some code example

**HTML**

```html
<table id="my-table">
  <tr id="default-row">
    <td class = "cell" contenteditable="true">3</td>
    <td class = "cell" contenteditable="true">10</td>
    <td class = "cell" contenteditable="true">56</td>
    <td class = "cell" contenteditable="true">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class = "cell" contenteditable="true">3</td>
    <td class = "cell" contenteditable="true">5</td>
    <td class = "cell" contenteditable="true">3</td>
    <td class = "cell" contenteditable="true">4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class = "cell" contenteditable="true">5</td>
    <td class = "cell" contenteditable="true">6</td>
    <td class = "cell" contenteditable="true">7</td>
    <td class = "cell" contenteditable="true">8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class = "cell" contenteditable="true">12</td>
    <td class = "cell" contenteditable="true">6</td>
    <td class = "cell" contenteditable="true">7</td>
    <td class = "cell" contenteditable="true">3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```js
const cellValues = []

var table = document.getElementById("my-table");
//iterate trough rows
for(var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
  //iterate trough columns
  for(var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
    cellValues.push(document.querySelector(".cell").textContent)
    //get text value of the cell
  }
}
console.log(cellValues)
```

Comment: `document.querySelector(".cell")` is the first cell. You’re not actually using `i` and `j` anywhere to target a specific cell.

Comment: It would be more straightforward to iterate over `document.querySelectorAll(".cell")` vs rows and columns.

Comment: Well, i guess i had to specify it first. The thing is, that i've tried, but it keeps returning undefined if i use one of them, so i would ask for a fully rewrited code if possible

Comment: thank you a lot, dude. I'd upvoted u if i could.

Comment: Try `table.rows[i].cells[j]`.

Comment: Actually, I see you already do that, you _already_ have `col` which is exactly the element you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using `i` and `j` inside of your loops at all, you always just query the first `.cell`.

You *could* do something like `table.querySelector('tr')[0].querySelector('.cell')[j]` but it's probably easier to use the `col` variable that you already have - which is exactly the element you are looking for!

```js
var table = document.getElementById("my-table");
//iterate trough rows
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
  //iterate trough columns
  for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
    cellValues.push(col.textContent)
    //get text value of the cell
  }
}
console.log(cellValues)
```

Alternatively, if you aren't interested in `i`, `j` or `row` much, you could just iterate over all the `.cell`s:

```js
const cellValues = [...document.querySelectorAll('.cell')]
  .map(cell => cell.textContent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple and clean. Just reuse the previous const's.
This way, you can add check up's if needed, and know what row your on.

```js
const cellValues = []

const table = document.getElementById("my-table");
//iterate trough rows
for (let i = 0; i <= table.rows.length - 1; i++) {
  // iterate trough columns
  for (let j = 0; j <= table.rows[i].cells.length - 1; j++) {
    // get text value of the cell
    cellValues.push(table.rows[i].cells[j].textContent)
  }
}
console.log(cellValues)
```

```html
<table id="my-table">
  <tr id="default-row">
    <td class="cell" contenteditable="true">3</td>
    <td class="cell" contenteditable="true">10</td>
    <td class="cell" contenteditable="true">56</td>
    <td class="cell" contenteditable="true">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell" contenteditable="true">3</td>
    <td class="cell" contenteditable="true">5</td>
    <td class="cell" contenteditable="true">3</td>
    <td class="cell" contenteditable="true">4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell" contenteditable="true">5</td>
    <td class="cell" contenteditable="true">6</td>
    <td class="cell" contenteditable="true">7</td>
    <td class="cell" contenteditable="true">8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell" contenteditable="true">12</td>
    <td class="cell" contenteditable="true">6</td>
    <td class="cell" contenteditable="true">7</td>
    <td class="cell" contenteditable="true">3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by other answers, the issue is `document.querySelector()` is selecting the first cell every time.

Another approach is to use `.reduce()` and `.map()`

```js
const table = document.getElementById("my-table");
const cells = [...table.rows].reduce((acc, row) => [
  ...acc,
  ...[...row.cells].map(cell => cell.textContent)
],[]);
console.log(cells)
```

```html
<table id="my-table">
  <tr id="default-row">
    <td class = "cell" contenteditable="true">3</td>
    <td class = "cell" contenteditable="true">10</td>
    <td class = "cell" contenteditable="true">56</td>
    <td class = "cell" contenteditable="true">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class = "cell" contenteditable="true">3</td>
    <td class = "cell" contenteditable="true">5</td>
    <td class = "cell" contenteditable="true">3</td>
    <td class = "cell" contenteditable="true">4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class = "cell" contenteditable="true">5</td>
    <td class = "cell" contenteditable="true">6</td>
    <td class = "cell" contenteditable="true">7</td>
    <td class = "cell" contenteditable="true">8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class = "cell" contenteditable="true">12</td>
    <td class = "cell" contenteditable="true">6</td>
    <td class = "cell" contenteditable="true">7</td>
    <td class = "cell" contenteditable="true">3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```